# Efficiently placing object randomly in a virtual 2D Environment

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an environment made of 2 dimensions. I would like my environment to be big (1000x1000 at least) and deals with at most that amount of entities.  For memory concerns I decided to not implement any 2D array or a vector of vector (am I wrong ?). I just have an Environment object with a width and height attributes, and an inner vector of Entities containing each an x and y attributes.

The first step for me is to initialize my environment by placing entities randomly in it. Only one entity can occupy a point in that space.

My first approach was somehow naive :

```
void Environment::placeEntities(unsigned int entity_quantity, unsigned int seed){
    srand(seed);
    
    while(entity_quantity > 0){
        unsigned int x = this->width % rand();
        unsigned int y = this->height % rand();
        if(emptySquare(x, y)){
            addEntity(new Entity(x, y));
            entity_quantity--;
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is getting very slow for a big number of Entities, I suppose that's due to the fact that an already occupied cell is checked many times before finding a free one.

For my second approach I thought of generating every possible squares in a list. Then taking out the last square, making a new Entity on that square, removing the square out of the list and continuing.

```
void Environment::placEntities(unsigned int entity_quantity){
    std::list<std::pair<unsigned short int, unsigned short int>> coordinates;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->height; i++){
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j){
            coordinates.push_back(std::pair<unsigned short int, unsigned short int>(i, j));
        }
    }
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end(), g);

    for(int i = entity_quantity; i > 0; i--){
        std::pair<unsigned short int, unsigned short int> last_cell = coordinates.back();
        addEntity(new Entity(last_cell.first, last_cell.second));
        coordinates.pop_back();
    }
}
```

This approach gives me some technical troubles (according to the compiler, it seems I can't shuffle on a list of pairs because some operators are not defined).

Do you know any other way I could place my entities effectively ?

Comment: It would help to have the complete error message you're getting, especially since your example is not copy/paste/compile ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change type of `coordinates` from

```
std::list<std::pair<unsigned short int, unsigned short int>> coordinates;
```

to

```
std::vector< std::pair<unsigned short int, unsigned short int> > coordinates;
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem I noticed on your first approach:

```cpp
    unsigned int x = this->width % rand();
    unsigned int y = this->height % rand();
```

Ignore the exact randomness of `rand()` for now, `rand()` would generate a number range between `0` to `RAND_MAX`, where `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to be at least `32767`, but often time it could be `2^31` or some really large number.

So for most of the time, you are just getting

```
    x = 1000 % aVeryLargeNumber;
    y = 1000 % aVeryLargeNumber;
```

which would get `x = 0, y = 0`.

What you meant is probably:

```cpp
    unsigned int x = rand() % this->width;
```